# A quick, easy mistyped question

Tags: steganography, letters, seasonal

Waht is the appareytln ewird solution to this mestyrious arndom question?

---

**Note:** Everything you need to solve the question is above, and when you get the solution it should be quite obvious that you're correct. There is nothing in this note that is actually part of the question; the purpose of this note is to clarify the question and to make this question meet the 'quality standards'.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer is

> Happy New Year. Swapping the letters that have been mistyped gives HA-PP-YN-EW-YE-AR

Comment: Good work on the second part!

Comment: ...They mistyped PP? How'd you figure that out?

Comment: Once I got HA, YN, EW, YE, AR it was obvious what was missing. Although you did have to jumble them up a bit as they didn't completely fit- it ended up HA, NY, WE, YE, RA.